# Laravel arrays in Session Not working in Ajax Request Dropzone

Tags: php, arrays, session, dropzone.js, laravel-5.6

```
$f = array('filename' => $filename,'allowed_filename' => $allowed_filename);
$files = [];
\Log::debug($form_data['request_timestamp']);

if (\Session::has( $form_data['request_timestamp'] )) {
    \Log::debug("Has");
    $files = json_decode( \Session::get(  $form_data['request_timestamp'] ) );
    $files[] = $f;
} else {
    \Log::debug("No");
    $files[] = $f;
}

\Session::put( $form_data['request_timestamp'], json_encode($files) );
\Log::debug(print_r(\Session::get( json_decode( $form_data['request_timestamp'] ) ),true));
```

And log file is

Ajax Request # 1

```
[2018-05-30 07:15:26] local.DEBUG: 1527664478  
[2018-05-30 07:15:26] local.DEBUG: No  
[2018-05-30 07:15:26] local.DEBUG: [{"filename":"1471354512314242835804528332297458594819513n","allowed_filename":"1471354512314242835804528332297458594819513n-5eca8.jpg"}]
```

Ajax Request # 2

```
[2018-05-30 07:16:04] local.DEBUG: 1527664478  
[2018-05-30 07:16:04] local.DEBUG: No  
[2018-05-30 07:16:04] local.DEBUG: [{"filename":"1471354512314242835804528332297458594819513n","allowed_filename":"1471354512314242835804528332297458594819513n-0701a.jpg"}]
```

I am trying to maintain array of file names on key( request_timestamp )

Comment: Do you go through the web middleware which initiates the session for this route?

Comment: it's just auth middleware and user is logged in